# What is the correct syntax for updating users MySQL password while specifying authentication plugin

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to update a users password while specifying the authentication plugin but I'm getting a syntax error, could someone tell me the correct syntax, please.

I'm using:

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```

Comment: What's the syntax error? What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: @Dharman
   2 errors were found during analysis:
    Missing comma before start of a new alter operation. (near "BY" at position 68)
    Unrecognized alter operation. (near "BY" at position 68)
   
   Server version: 10.4.17-MariaDB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are using MariaDB. MariaDB and MySQL have slightly different syntax and they mostly differ in the alternative keywords that can be used when specifying the identification method.

**For MariaDB** you can use `WITH <authmeth> AS PASSWORD(<password>)`

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password AS PASSWORD('passwordhash');
```

**For MySQL** your syntax will work as MySQL will hash the password for you automatically.

```
ALTER USER 'user'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';
```